# How do I search for substrings within strings in an array and add the relevant results to a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Why when I try to search for substrings within values of cardDescs and console log the results it just console logs an empty array

```
const cardDescs = [];

$.getJSON("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php", null, function(result){
  var i = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10767; i++){
    (cardDescs).push(result["data"][i]["desc"])
  }
})




function summonCardToFieldByName() {
  var cardName = document.getElementById('cN').value;
  const useableCards = [];
  for (description in cardDescs){
    if (description.includes("Special Summon 1 \""+cardName+"\" from your Deck")){
      useableCards.push({description});
    }
  }
  console.log(cardDescs[132]);
  console.log(useableCards);

}
```

The relevant relevant HTML

```
<form id="cardSearch">
          <input type="text" size="12" id="cN" />
          <input type="button" onclick="showChosenCard(); summonCardToFieldByName();" value="Submit Card" />
 </form>
```

Comment: ```useableCards.push({description});```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to include only *pertinent* code in your question relating directly to your problem. From what I can tell, your HTML and CSS is not relevant at all (and much of your JS). There is nothing in what you've posted that would explain why `cardDescs` has only 1 item in it, unless the source data itself has only 1 item.

Comment: For some reason putting the {} around description in the summonCardToFieldByName function allows me to index specific values in CardDescs but when I try to now search for substrings and add them to the new array, when I try to console log the new array it just console logs loads of empty arrays and nearly crashes my browser

Comment: See my earlier comment. Clean the question up, add your update to there (keep all information required for understanding your problem in the question itself) and perhaps someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see you calling the function at all before you do the console logging, so that might be the issue, you never fill the array with usable cards before logging it out.

Comment: oh sorry i should clarify that cN is the id of a user input ill edit the question to reflect some changes i made to the code

Comment: So I see you moved the logging up into the function, does it work now?

Comment: no unfortunatley, i moved it out of the for loop because that was causing it to log around 10,000 arrays instead of just one, but its still empty

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by using a for loop rather than a for/in loop and push the specific index from the array

```
    const cardDescs = [];

$.getJSON("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php", null, function(result){
  var i = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10767; i++){
    (cardDescs).push(result["data"][i]["desc"])
  }
})


    function summonCardToFieldByName() {
  var cardName = document.getElementById('cN').value;
  const useableCards = [];
  for (var i = 0; i <= 10767; i++){
    if (cardDescs[i].includes("Special Summon 1 \""+cardName+"\" from your Deck")){
      useableCards.push(cardDescs[i]);
    }
  }
```